# Add a component (Material) to a cube in unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to add a component (material) to a number of cubes.
I got an array of cubes and they have to get painted then. After the first cube Unity throws an error that says:

> MissingComponentException: There is no 'Material' attached to the
>   "Cube" game object, but a script is trying to access it

My code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameScene : MonoBehaviour {

SceneManager Changer;
public Scrollbar speed, size;
GameObject[,] cubes;
int sizer;    
Color mixer;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    size.value = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("sizeSecond");
    speed.value = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("speed");

    SetSize();

    cubes = new GameObject[sizer, sizer];

    GenerateCubes();

    mixer = new Color(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("red"), PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("green"), PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("blue"));


}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

public void GoBack() {
    SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("chosenScene", 1); //key setzen
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("speed", speed.value);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("sizeSecond", size.value);
}

void SetSize() {
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("size") == 0)
    {
        sizer = 20;
    }
    else if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("size") == 1)
    {
        sizer = 40;
    }
    else if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("size") == 2)
    {
        sizer = 60;
    }
}

void GenerateCubes() {
    for (int i = 0; i < sizer; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizer; j++)
        {

            cubes[i, j] = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube); //erzeugen
            cubes[i, j].transform.position = new Vector3(i -sizer / 2, j - sizer / 2, 0); // durch 2 damit es mittig angezeigt wird.
            cubes[i, j].GetComponent<Material>().color = mixer;

            Instantiate(cubes[i, j]);                               
        }
    }
}
}
```

sizer gets the amount of cubes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you generate cube with `GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);`, a cube is created with a `Mesh Renderer` attached to it **not** `Material`.

[image]

You can access the `Material` of the cube from the  `Mesh Renderer` component.

Simply Replace

```
cubes[i, j].GetComponent<Material>().color = mixer;
```

with

```
cubes[i, j].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = mixer;
```

Comment: @louis12356 Just a minor mistake for new Unity users. Don't forget to accept answer.

Comment: You are welcome. You don't have to put **solved** in a solved question. Accepting the answer will let people know that your problem is solved. I fixed the question for you and added the exact error message so that it will help others googling your exact problem. Happy coding!